# Linker cannot find library even with rpath set

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling a project to ARMv7. It's a C++11 project that uses CMake. To build the ARM-version, I use an arm toolchain file that configures the build system.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)

execute_process(
  COMMAND ${UTIL_SEARCH_CMD} ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE BINUTILS_PATH
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

get_filename_component(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR ${BINUTILS_PATH} DIRECTORY)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX /opt/cross/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-)
set(USER_LIB_PATH /opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf) 

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=armv7-a") # -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 

set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy CACHE INTERNAL "objcopy tool")
set(CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}size CACHE INTERNAL "size tool")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

(Error message abbreviated; left out some other libs that are unrelated to the problem)

```
 -o embedded -L/opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/mysql -L/opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/mysql -lpthread -lzip -lodb -lodb-mysql -lodb-boost && :
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libmysqlclient.so.18, needed by /opt/cross/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libodb-mysql.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/cross/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libodb-mysql.so: undefined reference to `mysql_stmt_fetch_column@libmysqlclient_18'
```

The linker error shows that the rpath is set correctly, and `libmysqlclient.so` is indeed in the given path. I would expect the linker to find the library fine.

```
⋊> ~ ll /opt/cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/mysql/                                                                                                                                                                                                                    19:12:34total 2.9M
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.7K Nov 30  2016 INFO_BIN
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  170 Sep 12  2016 INFO_SRC
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   17 Jun 11 12:44 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient.so*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   20 Jun 11 12:44 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.18*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   24 Jun 11 12:44 libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.9M Nov 30  2016 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  11K Nov 30  2016 mysqlbug*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 6.6K Nov 30  2016 mysql_config*
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Jun 11 12:44 plugin/
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# cmake-format: off
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/}*.h"
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/}*.hpp"
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/}*.hxx"
)
file(GLOB_RECURSE source CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cxx"
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.ixx"
)
# cmake-format: on

list(REMOVE_ITEM source "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")

add_library(embedded_lib OBJECT ${headers} ${source})

target_link_libraries(
    embedded_lib
    odb
    odb-mysql
)

target_link_directories(
    embedded_lib
    PUBLIC
    ${USER_LIB_PATH}/lib
    ${USER_LIB_PATH}/lib/mysql
)

add_executable(embedded "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(embedded embedded_lib)
```